# Detect power off button when i press four time in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hardware, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I am creating an application where I detect a 4-time press power button and perform some action on it I try my self but I unable to perform it please if you have any solution tell me

I am using **hardware_buttons: ^1.0.0** packages in my this application.

my code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:hardware_buttons/hardware_buttons.dart' as HardwareButtons;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: MyHomeScreen());
  }
}

class MyHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomeScreen({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomeScreenState createState() => _MyHomeScreenState();
}

class _MyHomeScreenState extends State<MyHomeScreen> {
  String _latestHardwareButtonEvent;
  var counter = 0;
 
  StreamSubscription<HardwareButtons.LockButtonEvent> _lockButtonSubscription;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
 
   
      _lockButtonSubscription =
          HardwareButtons.lockButtonEvents.listen((event) {
        setState(() {
          _latestHardwareButtonEvent = 'LOCK_BUTTON';
        });
      });
 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: Text("Hardware Interaction"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: there is already an issue mentioned on the repo regarding this and seems like you have to do it in native way

https://github.com/flutter-moum/flutter_hardware_buttons/issues/47#issuecomment-638885320

Comment: this issue is related to the volume button but I want the power button on the flutter